# Object Iteration PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, iteration

I have a question about the general functionality of PHP that I haven't been able to get a good, clean, simple answer on.

Say I have a class, student. And I create an array called Students that contains instances of the class student. How would I go about iterating through that array and pulling, say, StudentID off each of the student class instances? Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a class like this:

```
class Student {
    public $StudentId = 0;
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->StudentId = $id;
    }
}
```

And an array like this:

```
$students = array(
    new Student(1),
    new Student(2),
    ....
);
```

To get the StudentId of each, simply iterate through the array like any other normal array iteration:

```
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $id = $student->StudentId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all I was looking for. All I could find was the official PHP documentation, something about keys, and I didn't understand...

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($studentArray as $student)
{
    $studentId = $student->StudentId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `students` is a array, you can *iterate*  over that array gaining access to every object in the array:

```
foreach($students as $student) {
  echo $student->StudentID;
}
```